# Does a separate geared panning base exists?

Tags: tripod-heads

Looking at geared tripod heads it seems that the Arca Swiss Cube is the yardstick. There is a version of the Cube with gears for the panning motion as well as tilt/yaw [link to article](https://fstoppers.com/gear/arca-swiss-announces-new-tripod-heads-and-camera-support-products-147223) called the Cube GP (Geared Panning).

Now the Cube is out of my price range (and also is bigger and supports more weight than I need) so while looking at alternatives I came across [Leofoto G2](https://www.leofoto.com/products_detail.php?id=352) which is a MUCH cheaper and lighter alternative to the cube but this lacks the geared panning.

Is there separate Geared Panning plates out there that I could buy? I have searched for such a product but my google fu is weak.

The intended use case is precision framing using a long macro lens (for example Sigma 100-300mm f4 with extension tubes) but I will mostly do other kinds of photography so I want a compact head and not one with large handles sticking out ruling out Benro GD3WH and similar heads.

Comment: Are you adverse to a single-axis motion controller? The Syrp Genie Mini comes to mind.

Comment: @scottbb I had envisioned a non electronic solution, if that turns out not to exist I will have to rethink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few available.

### [Feisol PB-70](https://www.feisol.net/home/feisol-panning-base-pb-70.html)

[image]

The base in 70 mm wide with a 3/8"-16 UNC socket. The top is 60 mm wide, with a 3/8"-16 UNC stud. This is intended to be the panning base below other mounts, such as pan/tilt or ball heads. This should be mounted on a leveled tripod, or on top of a leveling base.

### [Sunwayfoto GC-01 geared clamp](http://www.sunwayfoto.com/e_goodsDetail.aspx?gId=1505)

[image]

The base diameter is 58 mm. Comes with a detachable Arca-style QR plate for the bottom. Does not come with an Arca-style top plate. This is intended to be the panning base/clamp on top of a ball head.

Comment: The sunwayfoto gc-01 apears to be exactly what I was searching for. Thanks

Comment: i have both the cube and the leofoto and they are both great, Cube is the best. the leofoto is good only for architecture as it has only 15deg or swing/tilt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a separate manual geared base available. There is the [Photo Clam Mutliflex](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1448420-REG/photo_clam_multifelx_gear_head_with.html) which is a cheaper version of the Cube.